# Knockout Style attribute float

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to align a div using a computed value using Knockout however this seams to have no affect on the attribute "Float". I am able to change the color using the same approach.
The UI should float div elements left/right based on their user group.

JFiddle Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/TMVAT/1/

```
    this.floatAlign = ko.computed(function() {
        if(this.employee() == undefined || this.employee()=="") {
            return "right";
        } else {
            return "left";
        }
    }, this);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Because your sample looks ok in the latest Chrome... the red texts of the right and the green text on the left...

Comment: I am using Firefox...

Comment: Sorry guys, me being a dumb ass. It's the browser compatibility war issue. This was a quick knockup as we have designers who make the finished layout...

Comment: Gizmo , Try the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **fixed** this issue with css binding . It's working perfect.

**Html Changes:-**

```
<div data-bind="style: { color: colour },css:{FloatLeft : floatAlign() ==  left',FloatRight : floatAlign() == 'right'}" style="width:65%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
```

**Css Changes:-**

```
.FloatLeft{
  float:left;
 }
.FloatRight{
  float:right;
 }
```

**Mark it as answer**